# Get file possibly to string on form submit

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to get a file on submit but i got this code snippet that gets it onchange. Truthfully i do not really understand the first line and how it transitions BUT basically i want to turn it to a function i can call when i click submit and without having the eventlistener there as sometimes it does not work unless called on the html form.

```
const fileSelector = document.querySelector('#a_pic');
fileSelector.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  const fileList = event.target.files;
  file = fileList[0];
  pic_url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  alert(file)
  document.querySelector('#secondcheck').innerHTML = '<img src = "' + pic_url + '">';
  a_pic = file;
});
```

Html code:

```
<form>
<input class= "form-control" type = "file" name= "a_pic" id= "a_pic" accept= "image/*">
<button type="button" value = "submit" name = "submit" id="submit" onclick = "whatever_the_newfunction_may_be()">submit</button>
```

Please any explanation is appreciated as i am relatively new green in javascript.

Comment: You need to use the `onchange` handler because it has reference to the files uploaded. Why not just store the file in a global variable (or one with shared scope) for future use and then use that global variable in the `onsubmit` method?

It's unclear what you mean by "it doesn't work unless called on the html form"

Comment: Sometimes onchange doesn't work from the javascript file but rather from the form element when appended to it

Comment: I tried your method by using a_pic. But when I try to display it outside the function block it shows me its a  .mqp file not the usual blob image. I don't know why either

Comment: @PhillipS answer worked, although your suggestion was also correct. However what i was trying to achieve is to run the entire process on submit. ie, putting everything in a function and get the file value when the submit happens and not onchange or oninput, I guess that can't happen. I don't see anything wrong in my question so i wonder why the downvote. I'm here to learn so if there's something wrong with my code I don't mind being enlightened.

Comment: As for the explanation I needed, I noticed the addEventListener('change', (event){...). I remember "function" has to be written to declare a function for it to be recognised as such, so I don't understand the transition where the first "event" was written, especially with the =>. I did check online but did not get an explanation related to this scenario.

Comment: Ah, yes you can also do `function(event) { ... event.target.files ... }` instead of the `()  => { }` is called an (ES6) arrow function and is almost the same thing, however, has a slightly different scope for `this` which can be a gotcha sometimes. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine. There's a variety of ways to handle a form submission, but here's one where you don't use the form's submit event but instead just a button's click event.

```js
  const fileSelector = document.querySelector('#a_pic');
  let picBlobUrl;
  fileSelector.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
    const fileList = event.target.files;
    file = fileList[0];
    picBlobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  });
  
  function submitClicked() {
    document.querySelector('#secondcheck').innerHTML = '<img src="' + picBlobUrl + '">';
  }
```

```html
<div>
<input class="form-control" type="file" name="a_pic" id="a_pic">
<button onclick="submitClicked()">submit</button>
</div>

<div id="secondcheck"></div>
```